# Select hyperlink in html document using Python and Selenium

Tags: python, html, selenium

I am trying to select a hyperlink in a document from a website, but not sure how to select it using Selenium.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
names = 'Catostomus discobolus yarrowi'
driver = webdriver.Firefox()
driver.get("http://ecos.fws.gov/ecos/home.action")
SciName = driver.find_element_by_id('searchbox')
SciName.send_keys(names)
SciName.send_keys(Keys.RETURN)
```

The above code gets to the page that I am interested in working on, but not sure how to select the hyperlink. I am interested in selecting the first hyperlink. The html of interest is

```
<a href="http://ecos.fws.gov/speciesProfile/profile/speciesProfile.action?spcode=E063" data-click="{&quot;p&quot;:1}">Zuni Bluehead Sucker (<strong>Catostomus discobolus</strong> yarrowi)</a>
</h4>
<div class='url'>ecos.fws.gov/speciesProfile/profile/speciesProfile.action?spcode=E063</div>


<span class='description'>
States/US Territories in which the Zuni Bluehead Sucker is known to or is believed to occur: Arizona, New Mexico; US Counties in which the Zuni ...
</span>
<ul class='sitelinks'></ul>
</div>
```

I am guessing I could use find_element_by_xpath, but have been unable to do so successfully. I will want to always select the first hyperlink. Also, the hyperlink name will change based on the species name entered.

Answer (score 0):

I added the following code:

```
SciName = driver.find_element_by_css_selector("a[href*='http://ecos.fws.gov/speciesProfile/profile/']")
SciName.click()
```

I should have read the selenium documentation more thoroughly.

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
SciName = driver.find_element_by_link_text("Zuni Bluehead Sucker")
SciName.click()
```